# Laravel redirect code 302 when submit form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I faced an issue where Laravel redirects me back to my form page after submitting the form.
I was trying to `return` my `$request` data to make sure I got the correct values.
But I ended up getting redirected back to the form.
[image]
Controller:

```
// ServiceController.php
public function saveServiceProgress(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $service = Service::find($id);
        
        $rules = $this->generateCustomRules($service);
        $request->validate($rules);
        $input = $request->all();
        return $request;
        // echo $input;
        // return view('services.edit', compact('service'));
    }
```

The form is a huge form with `switch case`, so I only show the form tag:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['services.saveServiceProgress', 'id' => $service->id],'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>'true']) !!}
```

The form consists for dynamic input based on the id passed into the controller. It has text inputs and file inputs as well. So its a very complex form. Currently I chose the simplest version of the form to test the functionalities.

Please shed some light (and probably some code) to help me with my problems! Thanks a lot!!!

**Update on route:**

```
Route::post('services/submit/{id}', [ServiceController::class, 'saveServiceProgress'])->name('services.saveServiceProgress');
```

**Update after fixing validator:**
Managed to submit the form, now starts working on handling file upload. Thanks @Rwd and @mahmoud\ magdy for pointing out my validation issues!

Comment: can you also show your route?

Comment: My guess would be your validation is failing.

Comment: @qadirpervez Ok. Please check the latest update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use Validator::make** to handle if yours validation if fails with custom errors response

**see this link** https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: Ya. Just found that I didn't put error display in my template. Adding that showing my error in generating validation rules. Fixed that and I'm good to go! Thanks!